# running mocha in Browser using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, browser, mocha.js

I cloud manage to run run Mocha tests in the browser using ES6 / Typescript like that:

```
// test.ts

import 'mocha/mocha.css';
import * as M from 'mocha/mocha-es2018';
import { expect } from 'chai';

M.setup('bdd');

// import more tests here

describe('test', () => {
  it('test1', () => {
    expect(true).to.true;
  })
});

M.run();
```

The build works (using vite), the html page shows up - all nice and fine. **BUT** of course I would love to add more tests like that:

```
import './unit/sum.spec.ts';
// more imports
```

Doing so - will cause this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: describe is not defined

Is there any way to make all those »mocha functions« globally available using es6?

Answer (score 1):

I could finally make it like that:

```
import 'mocha/mocha.css';
import * as M from 'mocha/mocha-es2018';

(async () => {

  M.setup('bdd');

  await Promise.all([
    import('./unit/add.spec'),
    import('./unit/sub.spec'),
    import('./component/calc.spec')
  ]);

  
  M.run();

})();
```